# Skipping Incompatible "lib path" when searching for ljsoncpp

Tags: c++, qt, dll, static

I cant figure out why the compiler isnt properly linked to the library, in my .pro file i included it like this:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Libraries/jsonlib/lib/ -ljsoncpp
LIBS += C:/Users/laner/Desktop/AlgoApplication/AlgoAppV02/AlgoAppV02/release/jsoncpp.dll
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Libraries/jsonlib/include/json
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Libraries/jsonlib/include/json
```

[and this is the .lib file and location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omAtP.png)

I obviously included the path as well but it is still giving me the errors

```
:-1: error: skipping incompatible C:\Users\laner\Desktop\AlgoApplication\Libraries\jsonlib\lib/jsoncpp.lib when searching for -ljsoncpp
:-1: error: skipping incompatible C:\Users\laner\Desktop\AlgoApplication\Libraries\jsonlib\lib/jsoncpp.lib when searching for -ljsoncpp
:-1: error: skipping incompatible C:\Users\laner\Desktop\AlgoApplication\Libraries\jsonlib\lib\jsoncpp.lib when searching for -ljsoncpp
:-1: error: cannot find -ljsoncpp
:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[And finally this is the compiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puNZa.png)

Hope this information help! And any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it built with the same compiler (msvc vs mingw) and for the same architecture (32 vs 64 bit)?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I am using vcpkg to build it so how can i tell and also was using jsoncpp library and i cant tell if its x64 which is what my program is built on.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Any idea other than wrong architecture/compiler?

Comment: I don't know about vcpkg, I'd probably try some of these to find out if the dll is 32 or 64 bit: https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows